# To place radiobuttons one below the other in html

Tags: html

The following code is a part of registration form.I need to place the radiobutton one below the other .

```
<ul class="user">
    <li class="label">Status</li>
    <li class="field">
        <li class="field">
            <input class="radio" type="radio" name="radiobt" value="A" checked="checked" />
            Active                                        
        </li>
        <li class="field">
            <input  class ="radio" type="radio" name="radiobt" value="I"  />            
            Inactive                                        
        </li>                                                
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Good...just go ahead :)

Comment: The radio buttons are in list items. All else being equal, list items render one below the other, so your code will already do that. (If all else is not equal, then you need to provide enough code to reproduce the problem, see http://www.sscce.org/ )

Comment: Please [learn to love labels](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200711/use_the_label_element_to_make_your_html_forms_accessible/)

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. Use [a validator](http://validator.w3.org)

Comment: You should use a new `<ul>` when you are nesting `<li>` 's

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/8WbbD/ so, what is the problem? Also you should be  doing something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/6Y24t/ Ideally would be tables. But that's something you should do on your own!

Comment: @DejaVu — Your example is confusing `<label>` with the `<legend>` of a fieldset. Each label is for a single control. (And don't use tables for layout).

Comment: @Quentin So using a table for your form is bad practice? I have made several forms and i found using a table to help me out alot.

Comment: Yes, tables are tools to structure data, not to layout things in a grid.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First change you html to below:

```
<ul class="user">
<li class="label">Status</li>
<li class="field">
    <ul>
        <li class="field">
            <input class="radio" type="radio" name="radiobt" value="A" checked="checked" />
            Active                                        
        </li>
        <li class="field">
            <input  class ="radio" type="radio" name="radiobt" value="I"  />            
            Inactive                                        
        </li>                                                
    </ul>
</li>
```

Now apply following css to bring your radiobutton below one another:

```
ul.user > li > ul > li { display: block; }
```

Hope it should resolve your issue.

Comment: May I know the reason of down voting to this!

Comment: vote up requires 15 reputations - this message is cmg